# How do you find unicode characters in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

The Julia extension for VSCode makes it nice and easy to use Unicode characters with latex-like syntax.  For example if I want a variable named with the symbol for pi in a unicode-aware language, I can just type `\pi<tab>` and get the symbol for pi!

But I can't figure out how to search for these characters.  The find boxes don't seem to do the same tab-completion on latex-like syntax.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Whoops!  I've just learned that the latex-like syntax is not a VSCode feature, it's the Julia extension.  I'll edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Write `\pi<tab>` in the editor which will convert it to the symbol
   `π` (you can also do `\pi<enter>` or `\pi<mouse-click first item in drop-down>`).
2. Copy the symbol `π` from the editor and paste it into the find box
   (`Ctrl+F`) and press enter.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I've been doing and now I fear that this is as good as it gets.  I was hoping there was a way to turn on the LaTeX autocompletion for the find box.